# FeignClient logs printing two configured Interceptor called, this is confusion to identify which one is actual at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, feign

I am using FeignClient for Rest API calls, here is Use case as explained below.

I am having 2 different Services which are Authorized with Basic Authentication, with both different Authentications.

[image]

Service-1(SpringBoot Microservice) running with below configuration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BasicAuthenticationPoint basicAuthenticationPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/api/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(basicAuthenticationPoint);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("XYZ").password("PQR").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Service-2(SpringBoot Microservice) running with below configuration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BasicAuthenticationPoint basicAuthenticationPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/api/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(basicAuthenticationPoint);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("abc").password("123").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

And from third Microservice I am trying to connect each with following code base,
`FeignClientConfiguration1`

```
import feign.Logger;
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;

@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration1 {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        System.out.println("Config-1");
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("XYZ", "PQR");
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor bearerTokenRequestInterceptor() {
        return (RequestTemplate template) -> template.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, String.format(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }
}
```

`FeignClientConfiguration2`

```
import feign.Logger;
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;

@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration2 {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        System.out.println("Config-2");
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("abc", "123");
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor bearerTokenRequestInterceptor() {
        return (RequestTemplate template) -> template.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, String.format(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    }    
}
```

My Feign Clients are as follows
`FeignClient1`

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import com.config.FeignClientConfiguration1;

@FeignClient( url = "http://localhost:8081", name = "FeignClient1", configuration = FeignClientConfiguration1.class)
public interface FeignClient1 {

    @GetMapping("/api/hello/{name}")
    ResponseEntity<Object> greetingMessage(@PathVariable String name);

}
```

`FeignClient1`

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import com.config.FeignClientConfiguration1;

@FeignClient( url = "http://localhost:8082", name = "FeignClient2", configuration = FeignClientConfiguration2.class)
public interface FeignClient2 {

    @GetMapping("/api/hello/{name}")
    ResponseEntity<Object> greetingMessage(@PathVariable String name);

}
```

During calling any of methods from my controller i.e.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(TEST_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_URL)
public class UtilityTestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private FeignClient1 client1;
    
    @Autowired
    private FeignClient2 client2;
    
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/check1", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(client1.greetingMessage("TestV1"), null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/check2", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test2() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(client2.greetingMessage("TestV2"), null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My loggers are

```
2022-01-05 23:06:09.961 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] ---> GET http://localhost:8081/api/hello/TestV1 HTTP/1.1
2022-01-05 23:06:09.961 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] Accept: application/json
2022-01-05 23:06:09.961 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] Authorization: Basic Y2hhbmRhbmEyOmNoYW5kYW5hMg==
2022-01-05 23:06:09.961 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] Authorization: Basic Y2hhbmRhbmE6Y2hhbmRhbmE=
2022-01-05 23:06:09.961 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 (12ms)
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] date: Wed, 05 Jan 2022 17:36:09 GMT
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] expires: 0
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] pragma: no-cache
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] set-cookie: JSESSIONID=2E037D8263A9DAC3D1F8E3957A3C4C54; Path=/; HttpOnly
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] transfer-encoding: chunked
2022-01-05 23:06:09.974 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] x-content-type-options: nosniff
2022-01-05 23:06:09.975 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] x-frame-options: DENY
2022-01-05 23:06:09.975 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
2022-01-05 23:06:09.975 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] 
2022-01-05 23:06:09.975 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] {"player":"TestV1","message":"Hello V2TestV1"}
2022-01-05 23:06:09.975 DEBUG 19552 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.m.e.o.test.gateways.FeignClient1       : [FeignClient1#greetingMessage] <--- END HTTP (46-byte body)
```

At both occasion in logs there are twice Authorization part is logged. So, here I am bit confused whether or not it is picking up correct interceptor or not.

**My Confusions are**

1. Why it is showing twice in loggers, does it going through each interceptors from different configurations ?
2. Will this possible to silent un related Interceptors ?
3. Does Feign client going through all of Interceptors that are registered in each configurational classes ?

**Note:** Although I am getting valid response, means it is cracking through with correct configured BasicAuth w.r.t. each methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are marking `FeignClientConfiguration1` and `FeignClientConfiguration2` classes with the `@Configuration` annotation, they'll be picked up "globally" for the Spring context which essentially means those beans relevant for Feign will be applied to all Feign clients.

I see you specified the `configuration` attribute on your `@FeignClient` annotation but that won't "undo" the global configuration.

The way to go is to remove the `@Configuration` annotation from `FeignClientConfiguration1` and `FeignClientConfiguration2` and use the `@FeignClient` configuration attribute only.

Comment: Awesome. Good job. :)